# Output Full Drupal Page in structured XML

Tags: xml, drupal

Is there a way to output a drupal page (full node with any views, blocks etc) in pure XML format?

Thanks,

Shadi

Comment: You could do this with a custom theme. See the Theming Guide: http://drupal.org/documentation/theme

Answer (score 3):

You can use template files to override the default output and send XML instead of HTML.

I'm not sure which version of Drupal you're using, but the principle is the same in both (GrayB gives the link to the theme docs in another answer).

For Drupal 7, you have to override `html.tpl.php`, which is normally in /modules/system, as this sets the surrounding HTML (which you'll basically get rid of). You'll also probably want to override `page.tpl.php` and/or `node.tpl.php`, depending on your needs.

If your theme's directory already has a `template.php`, you can add the following. If there is no `template.php` file, you can create one and add these lines (changing `yourtheme` to the actual theme name).

```
<?php
function yourtheme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
    /***
      * A bunch of other preprocess stuff you don't need to touch
      */

    // this works for a single page, check if node id = '3' 
    if (in_array('html__node__3', $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'])) {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__xml';
    }
}

function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
     /***
       * Same as above
       */
     $page_nids = $vars['node']->nid;
     if (!$vars['is_front'] && $page_nids == '3') {
         $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__xml';
     }
}
function yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
     /***
       * Same as above
       * You may not need this one, depending on how much control
       * you want over the XML output
       */
     $node_nid = $vars['nid'];
     if ($node_nid == 3) {
         $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__xml';
     }
}
```

This tells Drupal to look for templates with the names `html--xml.tpl.php` etc. You could also use something like `html--node--3.tpl.php` if you know you just want to theme node 3, but giving it a generic name makes it more flexible.

You can now add the appropriate theme files into your theme folder: `html--xml.tpl.php`, `page--xml.tpl.php` (and `node--xml.tpl.php` if you included the `node_preprocess` function above). Note that underscores in the suggestion variables above become dashes in the theme file names.

If these files don't already exist in your theme, you can either copy the original `tpl.php` files and change the names (look at an existing core theme to get these - as mentioned above, you can get the `html.tpl.php` from the /modules/system folder), or create new ones. Copying is probably easier so you can see what you're starting with and can roll back changes.

In your `html--xml.tpl.php`, you can delete all that HTML stuff and strip it down to the core output, as well as the XML headers:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); ?>
<?php print '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>
<document>
  <?php print $page; ?>
</document>
```

You can then do the same for the `page.tpl.php` according to your needs. This is what my stripped-down edition looked like:

```
  <?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
    <sidebar>
      <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); 
      print render($page['sidebar_first']);
      ?>
    </sidebar>
  <?php endif; ?>

        <pagenode><?php print render($page['content']); ?></pagenode>

  <?php if ($page['sidebar_second']): ?>
      <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Of course, yours will look quite different. After that, you can do whatever you like to place the blocks, menu items etc. that you want to render.

Answer (score 1):

Following example will create "XML" tab next to "View" and "Edit" tabs on node page:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function example_menu() {
  return array(
    'node/%node/xml' => array(
      'title' => 'XML',
      'page callback' => '_example_xml',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access callback' => 'node_access',
      'access arguments' => array('view', 1),
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    ),
  );
}

function _example_xml($node) {
  node_feed(array($node->nid));
}
```

In sake of simplicity I reused node_feed, you can replace it with own header

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

And xml builder.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a [working example on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31403/create-an-xml-page-by-a-custom-module/228154#228154). Basically all you need is [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) and customized versions of [`node_feed()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_feed/7.x), [`format_rss_channel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_rss_channel/7.x) and [`format_rss_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_rss_item/7.x).

Following blog post might be helpful as well.
https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/creating-rss-feeds-with-a-light-hand/